# Entity Framework Core makes multiple request if the result is a complex object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Since I use the entity framework core instate entity framework 6 a linq query with subquery (resulting in a complex result object) generates multiple request.

```
var stopps1 = await (
    from s in DbContext.Tourstopp
    where s.TourId == tourId
    orderby s.Seq
    select new
    {
        Stopp = s,
        a = (from ga in DbContext.GeplanteSdn
             from a in DbContext.Sdn
             where ga.TourstoppId == s.Id && ga.SdnId == a.Id
             select a.Art).FirstOrDefault()
    }
    ).ToListAsync();

// Queryies send to db:
//SELECT[s].[Id], [s].[Bis], [s].[KdnId], [s].[Seq], [s].[TourId], [s].[Von]
//    FROM[Tourstopp] AS[s]
//WHERE[s].[TourId] = @__tourId_0
//ORDER BY[s].[Seq]

//SELECT TOP(1) [a1].[Art]
//    FROM[GeplanteSdn] AS[ga1]
//CROSS JOIN[Sdn] AS[a1]
//WHERE([ga1].[TourstoppId] = @_outer_Id) AND([ga1].[SdnId] = [a1].[Id])

//SELECT TOP(1) [a1].[Art]
//    FROM[GeplanteSdn] AS[ga1]
//CROSS JOIN[Sdn] AS[a1]
//WHERE([ga1].[TourstoppId] = @_outer_Id) AND([ga1].[SdnId] = [a1].[Id])

//SELECT TOP(1) [a1].[Art]
//    FROM[GeplanteSdn] AS[ga1]
// ...
```

If I make the result flat, this doesn't happen.

```
var stopps2 = await (
    from s in DbContext.Tourstopp
    where s.TourId == tourId
    orderby s.Seq
    select new
    {
        Stopp = s.Id,
        a = (from ga in DbContext.GeplanteSdn
                from a in DbContext.Sdn
                where ga.TourstoppId == s.Id && ga.SdnId == a.Id
                select a.Art).FirstOrDefault()
    }
    ).ToListAsync();
// Query send to db:
//SELECT [s].[Id], (
//    SELECT TOP(1) [a0].[Art]
//    FROM [GeplanteSdn] AS [ga0]
//    CROSS JOIN [Sdn] AS [a0]
//    WHERE ([ga0].[TourstoppId] = [s].[Id]) AND ([ga0].[SdnId] = [a0].[Id])
//)
//FROM [Tourstopp] AS [s]
//WHERE [s].[TourId] = @__tourId_0
//ORDER BY [s].[Seq]
```

How can I prevent this and send only one request like in the good old times with entity framework 6 ;)?

Comment: Unfortunately this is the behavior of even the latest at this time EF Core 2.0. By idea it would never be a single query, but one for each sub collection. But it shouldn't be N + 1 queries for sure. Consider it being current EFC limitation/bug/incomplete feature. All you can do is to wait it to be fixed in some future EFC release...

Comment: This seems to be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557003/entity-framework-core-count-does-not-have-optimal-performance

Comment: I think it's related to [#9282 Query: improve include pipeline so it can be reused for queries projecting composed collection navigations (filters and projections)](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9282) referred as **Reduce n+1 queries** in their [Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap#ef-core-20-under-development). And looking at the Roadmap, most likely it will not be addressed by the next 2.1 release.