# LINQ does not produce COUNT() query on group using EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a ASP.NET Core application which works on an SQL Server 2012 via EF Core. What I want to achieve is counting the size of different groups like

```
from b in this._context.Benchmark
group b by b.Device into g
select new {
    Device = g.Key,
    Count = g.Count()
}
```

The problem is that the whole thing is extremely slow, and the reason for that seems to be that the SQL statement does not map to a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)`, but according to the debugger, the application requests everything and performs the counting on the CPU. The query I get from the debugger's event window looks like:

```
SELECT [b0].[ID], [b0].[CreateDate], [b0].[Creator], [b0].[Device], [b0].[Environment], [b0].[Machine], [b0].[Name], [b0].[Plugin], [b0].[RunDate]
FROM [Benchmark] AS [b0]
ORDER BY [b0].[Device]
```

I can also see that the memory consumption of the IIS Express I use for debugging is insane for a simple `COUNT()`, so I tend to believe that this is the actual query.

The question is: how can i rephrase the query such that it actually maps to a `COUNT()`?

**Edit**: I have tried the very same query on the "real" EF and `ctx.Database.Log = Console.Write`, which produces the expected `COUNT()` query, which makes me believe this is an issue of EF Core.

Comment: Does it help if you do `let count = g.Count()` before the select? I will assume it doesn't, but could you try, and then use the `count` variable inside the `new { ... }` expression.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The query looks exactly the same.

Comment: You are saying Linq-To-SQL in your tag. With Linq To SQL (not core) it produces: SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count], ..
FROM ..
GROUP BY [t0].[...]

Comment: @CetinBasoz I have updated the title

Comment: I did some further research, and it seems that this is a known limitation of EF Core: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557003/entity-framework-core-count-does-not-have-optimal-performance

Comment: OK, it looks like that my version of EF Core was too old. Version 2.1.2 produces the expected query.

Comment: You still have Linq-To-SQL tag.

Comment: If you would, please add your answer as the accepted answer. It will benefit the community.

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet, but I will accept another one with the same content ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upgrade EF Core to version 2.1.2, it’s supported now.

Answer (score 0):

> The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([x.Device], [x])' could not be translated
> and will be evaluated locally.
>
> The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be
> evaluated locally.

The above logs are from my later test results, which show that `GroupBy`& `Count()` are not supported yet to translate full LINQ to SQL, then directly execute full SQL in database, **now EF Core has to fetch all data first, then `GroupBy` results locally. So, if your data is huge, then the performance will be very bad.**

You have to hard code a simple SQL to do your work in database directly, then the performance will be back to normal.

I upgraded to EF Core 2.1.2, tried the following code both in `MySQL` and `MS SQL`:

```
var query = _context.Benchmark.GroupBy(x => x.Device, 
              (key, group) => new  //Result selector
              {
                  Device = key,
                  Count = group.Count()
              });
await query.ToListAsync();
```

The result selector is right inside `GroupBy` which will make sure whether it could be translated to right SQL, bit unfortunately, it's NOT.

Here is another tricky, avoid to use `Count`:

```
var query = _context.Benchmark.GroupBy(x => x.Device, 
              (key, group) => new  //Result selector
              {
                  Device = key,
                  Count = group.Select(g => g.Id)//Avoid to use Count
              });
await query.ToListAsync();
```

The C# code produces the following logs by [this tool](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/entity-framework-core-and-linq-to-entities-3-logging-and-tracing-queries):

```
2018-08-24T14:27:26.6737424-04:00 Information 10403 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure
Entity Framework Core 2.1.2-rtm-30932 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql' with options: None
2018-08-24T14:27:31.4270317-04:00 Debug 10101 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
Compiling query model: 
'from IGrouping<Device, Benchmark> <generated>_0 in 
    (from Benchmark x in DbSet<Benchmark>
    select [x]).GroupBy([x].Device, [x])
select new <>f__AnonymousType3<Device, int>(
    [<generated>_0].Key, 

        (from Benchmark <generated>_1 in [<generated>_0]
        select [<generated>_1]).Count()
)'
2018-08-24T14:27:31.4319437-04:00 Debug 10104 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
Optimized query model: 
'from IGrouping<Device, Benchmark> <generated>_0 in 
    (from Benchmark x in DbSet<Benchmark>
    join Device x.Device in DbSet<Device>
    on Property([x], "DeviceId") equals Property([x.Device], "Id")
    select [x]).GroupBy([x.Device], [x])
select new <>f__AnonymousType3<Device, int>(
    [<generated>_0].Key, 

        (from Benchmark <generated>_1 in [<generated>_0]
        select [<generated>_1]).Count()
)'
```

Here is core LOGS, which shows the `GROUPBY` is not supported yet:

> ```
> 2018-08-24T14:27:31.4431635-04:00 Warning 20500 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
> The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([x.Device], [x])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
> 2018-08-24T14:27:31.4476637-04:00 Warning 20500 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
> The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
> 2018-08-24T14:27:31.4511652-04:00 Warning 20500 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
> The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
> ```

Here is rest logs after:

```
2018-08-24T14:27:31.4608060-04:00 Debug 10107 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
(QueryContext queryContext) => IAsyncEnumerable<<>f__AnonymousType3<Device, int>> _InterceptExceptions(
    source: IAsyncEnumerable<<>f__AnonymousType3<Device, int>> _SelectAsync(
        source: IAsyncEnumerable<IGrouping<Device, ValueBuffer>> _GroupBy(
            source: IAsyncEnumerable<TransparentIdentifier<ValueBuffer, Device>> _ShapedQuery(
                queryContext: queryContext, 
                shaperCommandContext: SelectExpression: 
                    SELECT `x.Device`.`Id`, `x.Device`.`Description`, `x.Device`.`IP`, `x.Device`.`Name`, `x.Device`.`Port`
                    FROM `Benchmark` AS `x`
                    INNER JOIN `Device` AS `x.Device` ON `x`.`DeviceId` = `x.Device`.`Id`
                    ORDER BY `x.Device`.`Id`, 
                shaper: TypedCompositeShaper<ValueBufferShaper, ValueBuffer, BufferedOffsetEntityShaper<Device>, Device, TransparentIdentifier<ValueBuffer, Device>>), 
            keySelector: (TransparentIdentifier<ValueBuffer, Device> t0) => t0.Inner, 
            elementSelector: (TransparentIdentifier<ValueBuffer, Device> t0) => t0.Outer), 
        selector: (IGrouping<Device, ValueBuffer> <generated>_0 | CancellationToken ct) => Task<<>f__AnonymousType3<Device, int>> _ExecuteAsync(
            taskFactories: new Func<Task<object>>[]{ () => Task<object> _ToObjectTask(Task<int> Count(
                        source: IAsyncEnumerable<ValueBuffer> _ToAsyncEnumerable(<generated>_0), 
                        cancellationToken: queryContext.CancellationToken)) }, 
            selector: (object[] results) => new <>f__AnonymousType3<Device, int>(
                <generated>_0.Key, 
                (int)results[0]
            ))), 
    contextType: Sequencer.Updater.Data.ApplicationDbContext, 
    logger: DiagnosticsLogger<Query>, 
    queryContext: queryContext)
2018-08-24T14:27:31.4825759-04:00 Debug 20000 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection
Opening connection to database 'TestDB' on server 'localhost,3306'.
2018-08-24T14:27:31.4877302-04:00 Debug 20001 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection
Opened connection to database 'TestDB' on server 'localhost,3306'.
2018-08-24T14:27:31.4901269-04:00 Debug 20100 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command
Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT `x.Device`.`Id`, `x.Device`.`Description`, `x.Device`.`IP`, `x.Device`.`Name`, `x.Device`.`Port`
FROM `Benchmark` AS `x`
INNER JOIN `Device` AS `x.Device` ON `x`.`DeviceId` = `x.Device`.`Id`
ORDER BY `x.Device`.`Id`
2018-08-24T14:27:31.4929857-04:00 Information 20101 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command
Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT `x.Device`.`Id`, `x.Device`.`Description`, `x.Device`.`IP`, `x.Device`.`Name`, `x.Device`.`Port`
FROM `Benchmark` AS `x`
INNER JOIN `Device` AS `x.Device` ON `x`.`DeviceId` = `x.Device`.`Id`
ORDER BY `x.Device`.`Id`
2018-08-24T14:27:31.5231128-04:00 Debug 20300 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command
A data reader was disposed.
2018-08-24T14:27:31.5270399-04:00 Debug 20002 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection
Closing connection to database 'TestDB' on server 'localhost,3306'.
2018-08-24T14:27:31.5303748-04:00 Debug 20003 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection
Closed connection to database 'TestDB' on server 'localhost,3306'.
```

Here is my environment:

```
PM> dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.401
 Commit:    91b1c13032

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.16299
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.401\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.3
  Commit:  124038c13e

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: This answer is confusing.  Can you please update the comments at the top to explain it a little further?  I would appreciate it for my benefit.

Comment: Updated. Both `GroupBy` and `Count()` are not supported yet. You have to use SQL instead.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer is incorrect or maybe misleading.  As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1) -> `GroupBy()` is indeed supported in EF Core 2.1 and later. However, it most likely only supports simplistic GroupBy() at this time. And I don't know when Count() was added, but it's there as far as I know.

Comment: @AdamVincent Yep,I saw the document this afternoon, but actually it's very easy to test it with the tools I mentioned: https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/entity-framework-core-and-linq-to-entities-3-logging-and-tracing-queries