# Entity Framework Core select/project optional one to one specific columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, projection

I am trying to retrieve a subset of properties in in Entity Framework Core (1.1.1) for an optional one-to-one relationship, but my query attempts result in all columns being retrieved in the query for both tables (verified with SQL Profiler).

For an example, lets say I have these models bound up to my DbContext:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteIceCream { get; set; }
    public string OtherRandomInfoForExample { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentAddress Address { get; set; }

}

public class StudentAddress 
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

When I try projecting this into a new model choosing only the columns I want like the following:

```
var studentsCityInfos = _dbContext.Student.AsNoTracking().Select(s => new StudentCityInfo
            {
                Id = s.StudentId,
                Name = s.StudentName,
                City = s.Address.City
            }).ToList();
```

The result is a query that returns all columns both tables. I have also tried the following with a null check on the navigation property and that leads to the same results:

```
var studentsCityInfos = _dbContext.Student.AsNoTracking().Select(s => new StudentCityInfo
            {
                Id = s.StudentId,
                Name = s.StudentName,
                City = s.Address == null ? null : s.Address.City
            }).ToList();
```

Is this maybe just a projection bug in EF Core 1.1.1 that should be optimized?

Any alternative approaches anyone else can think of?

As a fall back I can break this up into two queries or use FromSql to write my own, but I would like to know the correct approach to this scenario.

For completeness I have no control over the schema and both tables have many more columns and roughly a million rows.

Thank you for taking the time to read and provide answers!

EDIT: as requested, here is an example of the sql profiler results (manually made to reflect the results from my scenario):

```
SELECT [s].[StudentId], [s].[StudentName], [s].[Birthday], [s].[FavoriteIceCream], [s].[OtherRandomInfoForExample], [s].[BusinessFullName], [s].[BusinessLastName], [s.Address].[StudentId], [s.Address].[Address1], [s.Address].[Address2], [s.Address].[City], [s.Address].[Zipcode], [s.Address].[State], [s.Address].[Country]
FROM [Student] AS [s]
LEFT JOIN [StudentAddress] AS [s.Address] ON [s].[StudentId] = [s.Address].[StudentId]
ORDER BY [s.Address].[StudentId]
```

Comment: Can you provide the query in sql profiler ?

Comment: Sounds like the same issue as [EFCore returning too many columns for a simple LEFT OUTER join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544642/efcore-returning-too-many-columns-for-a-simple-left-outer-join)

Comment: @H.Herzl just added what the profiler resulting query looks like. Ivan some of those scenarios look really similar, I'll dive down that path and see if there is a related open issue.

Comment: Bug as reported here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6647